# Should I repeat my code or use if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A question from a friend:

I have multiple usages for the same code, let's say a vertical HTML card. I change the title and a lot of data based on the react component.

it feels unnecessary performance-wise and for readability to use "if statement" multiple times on the same page, so wondering shall I just repeat the code or just keep going?

my code looking something like that:

```
<test value={this.state.welcomePage ? 
    "hello" : this.state.supportPage ?
    "Contact Us" : 
    "Something else" 
}/>
```

Comment: It would be easier to follow your question if you gave us examples of both of the options you are considering.

Comment: See [How to Refactor Your Complex Nested ‘if-else’ Code?](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-refactor-your-complex-nested-if-else-code-28aa162047d5)

Comment: See also [Better Software Without If-Else](https://medium.com/swlh/5-ways-to-replace-if-else-statements-857c0ff19357)

Comment: ... I would also google for "refactor + if + else"

Comment: I don't know your exact scenario , maybe these 5 things might help you:
https://medium.com/swlh/5-ways-to-replace-if-else-statements-857c0ff19357

Answer (score 1):

That's a horrible anti-pattern. Probably the correct answer is to pass the variable bits in through the component properties and component children. Another possibility would be to create a base component and subclass it for various uses. Hard to say more without a more complete sample.